# Put value in cookie when radio button is clicked with jquery

Tags: jquery, cookies, radio-button

I have a wordpress plugin that generates 2 radiobutton. For conformation i'd like to display the value of the last radio button clicked on the next page.

I thought i would do this with a cookie and jquery.
What i've got is this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var verzend = $.cookie("verzend")
    $('input:radio[value="OrderWeight-0]').click(function () {
        $.cookie('verzend', 'verzenden')
    });
    $('input:radio[value="OrderWeight-1]').click(function () {
        $.cookie('verzend', 'afhalen')
    });
</script>
```

Unfortuanly it's not working. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You should try with the *change* event, more adapted to radio input.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var verzend = $.cookie("verzend")
    $('input:radio').on('change', function() {
        if ($(this).val() === "OrderWeight-0") {
            $.cookie('verzend', 'verzenden')
        } else {
            $.cookie('verzend', 'afhalen')
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It's not working unfortunally. But i'm wondering, how does your code 'know' wich radiobutton is clicked? Because the radiobutton have identical names and classes. Only the value is differant.

Comment: `$(this).val()` is giving you the selected value of your input, which canbe a radio or another input.